# Reporting Services and RDL files

Tags: sql, reporting-services, rdl

Can anyone guide me as to the best way to display the RDL file name of a report on the actual report when it is generated?

Say in the top corner or such like?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the report name on a report, you can use the built-in field:

```
Globals!ReportName
```